# What is the low latency event sourcing service in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-sqs, amazon-kinesis, aws-event-bridge

I am using `EventBridge` as event bus in our application. Based on its doc: https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/faqs/, the latency between sending and receiving an event is half second which is unacceptable in my application.

I am thinking about other alternatives. Kinesis has a problem about filtering events. Once a consumer attaches on a stream, it needs to provide some logics to filter out uninterested events. Since I am using lambda as the consumer and there will be many uninterested events trigger my lambda which will lead to high AWS bill.

AWS SNS can only support target of AWS services.

Another option is Kafka. But I can't find what the latency is when using AWS managed Kafka service.

What is the lowest latency event sourcing solution when using AWS

Comment: SNS support http targets, so it can be anything, not necessarily AWS service.

Answer (score 3):

Kinesis is probably the best way to go now, thanks to the newly release "event filtering" feature. This allows you to configure an event source mapping which filters kinesis (or SQS, Dynamo Streams) events.

Doing this means you can use Kinesis as an event bus, without having to invoke a lambda with every event.

See: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/aws-lambda-event-filtering-amazon-sqs-dynamodb-kinesis-sources/